# Pass content of a < table > tag from one JSP to another JSP page in the same format using JS or by any other method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I need to pass content of a  tag from one JSP to another JSP page in the same format using JS or by any other method.
i.e. I have a JSP page with data inside  tag, I want all this data to be replicated or copied to a new JSP page.(The data in table is quite large).
Here is the code.

Input Page

```
<table id="sample" align="left" border="2">
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th>Text Data</th>
            <th>Number Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        %>
        <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
            <td align="center"><%=i + 1%></td>
            <td align="center">This is text data <%=i%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=i * i%></td> 
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Desired Output

```
<table id="sample" align="left" border="2">
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th>Text Data</th>
            <th>Number Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        %>
        <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
            <td align="center"><%=i + 1%></td>
            <td align="center">This is text data <%=i%></td>
            <td align="center"><%=i * i%></td> 
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried doing that using JS code written below
    save a copy

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function savecopy() {
        var tabledata = document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML;
        window.open("newPage.jsp?data="+tabledata, '');
    }
</script>
```

When I run this code new blank window opens.
Kindly, suggest me the solution.

Comment: What's the difference between the input page and the desired output?

Comment: By desired output means I want exactly same table with data on the new JSP page.